# Output of adaptive.density function in spatstat

Tags: r, kernel-density, spatstat

I'm reading the book "Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R", Chapter 6, trying to replicate all the examples following the code at the [companion website](http://book.spatstat.org/chapter-code/chapter06.html). I cannot replicate Figure 6.15 (a) since this is the output I get and it's way different from the Figure in the book.

```r
library(spatstat)
#> Carico il pacchetto richiesto: spatstat.data
#> Carico il pacchetto richiesto: nlme
#> Carico il pacchetto richiesto: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.60-1       (nickname: 'Swinging Sixties') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'

swp <- rescale(swedishpines)
aden <- adaptive.density(swp, f=0.1, nrep=30)
#> Computing 30 intensity estimates...
#> 
#>      PLEASE NOTE:  The components "delsgs" and "summary" of the
#>  object returned by deldir() are now DATA FRAMES rather than
#>  matrices (as they were prior to release 0.0-18).
#>  See help("deldir").
#>  
#>      PLEASE NOTE: The process that deldir() uses for determining
#>  duplicated points has changed from that used in version
#>  0.0-9 of this package (and previously). See help("deldir").
#> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  30.
#> Done.
rainsat <- function(n) {
  grade <- sqrt(seq(0.1, 1, length=n))
  rainbow(n=n, start=1/2, s=grade)
}


par(mar = c(1, 0, 0, 2))
plot(aden, main="", ribscale=1000, col=rainsat)
plot(swp, add=TRUE, pch=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What's the problem here? What am I doing wrong? Even if I run all the code in the `startup.R` and `figurelayout.R` files (which should just change the cols of the plots making the b/w) I still cannot get the same plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adaptive.density` involves randomisation. You will not get the same result if you repeat the same command twice (unless you reset `random.seed`).
 A larger value of `nrep` will reduce the random variation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Btw: Did you change anything in the `bw.ppl` function? Because when I run `bw.ppl(rescale(swedishpines), ns = 128)` I get `sigma = 6.931089` while on the book (page 171) you get `sigma = 4.036`.

Comment: Changes in `spatstat` are documented in `vignette("updates")`. The default range of bandwidths in `bw.ppl` has changed. In both the old and new code, `bw.ppl(swedishpines)` is selecting the largest bandwidth in the search interval - this happens because there's not much evidence for inhomogeneity so the ideal bandwidth is very large.